# How to calculate Annual Percentage Rate

Tags: credit, interest

How to calculate **Annual Percentage Rate (APR)** given the following:

A - Loan borrowed at the beginning (USD 1000),
B - Loan total costs paid at the end (USD 2000),
c - Number of compounding periods per year (52 weeks),
k - Number of periods to pay the loan (60 weeks)

All the formulas found in literature use *nominal interest rate* but here we do not have it.

By APR I mean:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate

I have constructed a spreadsheet where I can find APR with Excel Solver by changing *nominal interest rate*. Wouldn't there be more elegant solution for that?

Comment: Your reference gives two definitions for APR.  Which do you want?

Comment: Is this a real situation you are facing? The rate is too high to reflect anything a lender in the US would charge.

Comment: Are there any payments in addition to the $2000 at the end of the loan period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APR for a loan with constant repayments made at regular intervals can be calculated by solving this formula:

http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html

```
s = 1000;
n = 52;
t = 60/52;
```

The periodic payments amount to a total cost of $2,000.

```
pp = 2000.0/60;
```

This next step solves `pp = (s p)/(1 - (1 + p)^(-n t))` for `p`.  (*Mathematica* used.)

```
p = Last@Reduce[pp == (s p)/(1 - (1 + p)^(-n t)), p, Reals]
```

> 0.0263204

Calculating the effective annual interest rate, `r`, from the periodic rate, `p`:

```
r = (1 + p)^52 - 1
```

> 2.86112

The effective annual rate is 286.11 %

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate

or, if a nominal rate, `i`, is required:

```
i = p * 52 = 0.0263204 * 52 = 136.9 % nominal rate compounded weekly
```

***Calculation Check***

Checking the principal is calculated correctly.  This is basically the summation in the page linked in the OP's question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#European_Union

i.e. `s = Σ pp (1 + r)^-(k/n)` for `k = 1 to 60`

The loan formula used earlier is actually [inducted from the summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039786/induction-of-closed-form-of-summation).

So, running the check by back-calculating the loan principal:

```
Sum[pp (1 + r)^-(k/n), {k, 60}]
```

> 1000

Yup, checks out.

Note the summation uses the effective annual rate, not the nominal rate.

Comment: Are there any periodic payments, or only the "loan total cost paid at the end"?

Comment: Yes, there are 60 periodic payments of `$2000/60 = $33.333`

Comment: 286%. This is why it seemed a hypothetical. Don't we have a maximum rate in the US?

Comment: Lol, yeah, check out pay-day loans! - http://www.bbc.co.uk/consumer/24746198

Comment: I follow your computations, but the effective APR comes out a bit higher than it seems like it should be to me (particularly when figuring out the rate for using in a basic mortgage type calculator that I modified to work with this structure, which would be much lower - less than half that).  I know 'effective interest rate' and actual rate are different, but I wonder if you could explain the meaning behind the terms, particularly when you expand by (1+p)^52 (which is where I am not as sure I understand the meaning of the different 'rates').

Comment: Is 'effective interest rate' equivalent to 'the interest you'd pay if you didn't make any payments at all on the product and capitalized all of the interest'?

Comment: For a nominal rate it's `i = p * 52 = 0.0263204 * 52 = 1.36866 = 136.9 %` compounded weekly.  The conversion between nominal and effective rate is detailed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation  I.e. `p = (1 + i/52)^52 - 1 = 2.86113 = 286.11 %`

Comment: @Chris Degnen I appreciate your answer. My equation is slightly different although I get the same result. `PeriodicPayment=L(i/c)/(1-(1+i/c)^(-k))` and the second equation is `PeriodicPayment=B/k=USD33.33`. I use symbols defined in my question. `i` means nominal interest rate compound weekly. I do not get your idea of introducing `t`. Can you also please explain what `p`means in your notation. And finally, will we get the same APR with this method of calculation and the method defined by EU?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#European_Union Can you please explain what the `A_K` and `t_K` mean in that formula - perhaps using our example? I guess that `A_K` is equal installment of USD 33.33, `K`=60, what about `t_K`?

Comment: Hi Przemyslaw. In the formula `n t = k`, and `p` is the periodic (weekly) interest rate, so `p = i/52`. In the wiki link `t_K` is a time period for each payment, written simply as `k/n` in my basic version of the summation. `A_K` is a payment amount for each period, which we have as a constant $33.33. These methods are applicable everywhere. The only difference is the result may be quoted as effective annual rate or nominal rate compounded over some interval.  Nevertheless, conversion to effective annual rate `r` is required for the summation, which is the clearest presentation for a reader.

Comment: Przemyslaw, please note I have used `k` in the summation as an iterator, so `k/n` is ranging from `1/52` to `60/52`.

Comment: Addressing your question: "will we get the same APR with this method of calculation and the method defined by EU?" Yes. The formula is directly derived from the summation by induction, see [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039786/induction-of-closed-form-of-summation). However, the EU notation allows for variable payment amounts and variable intervals. We are using constant payments and constant intervals. This is also the assumption for the formula. So to reiterate (pun not intended), for a loan with constant, regular repayments, the summation and its formula are the same thing.

Comment: Chris, in your formula `pp = (s p)/(1 - (1 + p)^(-n t))` you use `p` while I in the same place use `i/c` with `i` meaning nominal interest rate compound weekly and `c` is a number of compounds. Am I doing wrong, although I get the same results for APR?

Comment: Przemyslaw, that's all fine. The nominal interest rate, `i` is defined as the periodic interest times the number of compounding intervals per annum, so `i = p c`.  See also the equivalence of `i/n` and `j` in this calculation section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation

Comment: I have made an Excel VBA function to calculate APR here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050109/excel-vba-formula-for-apr/28084325#28084325 Any remarks shall be very welcome.